# return error 410 for location regex? in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm using `nginx-1.6.2,2` and I'd like return `error 410` for URL that matches `/browse.php?u=http`, so requests such as this will get 410:

```
162.218.208.16 - - [21/Nov/2014:12:35:40 -0500] "GET /browse.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3DBroke%2C%2BUSA%2Bfiletype%3Apdf%26first%3D0%26count%3D20%26format%3Drss&b=156&f=norefer HTTP/1.1" 403 570 "http://ww.thespacesurf.com/browse.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3DBroke%2C%2BUSA%2Bfiletype%3Apdf%26first%3D0%26count%3D20%26format%3Drss&b=156&f=norefer" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"
```

I don't really need `regex`, so something like this, but it's not working:

```
location = /browse.php?u=http {
        return 410;
}
```

---

couple of days later, I `grep -c` for `410` in `/var/log/nginx-access.log`

```
$ bzip2 -cd /var/log/nginx-access.log.0.bz2 | grep -c ' 410 '
5665
$
```

and that made me feel warm and fuzzy) thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because location is `/browse.php`, not the one you specified.

There are several ways to do it. For example, something like this should do:

```
location = /browse.php {
        if ($query_string ~ ^u=http) {
                return 410;
        }
}
```

P.S.: or use `~*` instead of `~` if `u=http` is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 4):

You can't match the query string in the declaration of a location statement so you need something like this :

```
location = /browse.php {
    if ($arg_u ~ "^http") { 
        return 410;
    }
}
```

Comment: while I like your answer is better then @nochkin, I'm trying to stay away from `regex`, so I'll vote your answer up! Thanks again!

Comment: @alexus It won't match the example you gave so.

Comment: right, I was just testing it and I came up to that conclusion too.

Comment: Just for completeness, the $arg_u matches the query parameter u. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables