# nginx php-fpm not fully working

Tags: nginx, freebsd, php-fpm

I'm using `nginx-1.6.2_1,2` with `php5-5.4.36` on:

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD X.X.X 9.2-RELEASE-p5 FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE-p5 #0 r265974: Wed May 14 07:57:04 PDT 2014     root@X.X.X:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/R610  amd64
#
```

**nginx**:

```
# cat X.conf 
server {
    listen      X.X.X.X:80;
    server_name X;
    root        /home/X/X/;
    index       index.php;
    include     _includes/_location-php.include;
    include     _includes/4XX.include;
}
# cat _location-php.include 
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
}
#
```

The issue is: I'm getting different behaviour whenever I hit `/index.php` and `/browse.php`

```
# curl -I http://X/index.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 20 Jan 2015 17:07:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 7219
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: s=oa6u7nscersjad58fcfgk98174; path=/
Last-Modified: Wed, 31 Dec 2014 07:06:32 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache

# curl -I http://X/browse.php   
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 20 Jan 2015 17:07:16 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 50107
Last-Modified: Wed, 31 Dec 2014 07:06:12 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "54a3a064-c3bb"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

#
```

`/index.php` works as expected and `/browse.php` returns me PHP code.

I also created `phpinfo.php` and placed it in root as well, it works as expected it.

```
# curl -I http://X/phpinfo.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 20 Jan 2015 17:16:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive

#
```

Comment: are index.php and browse.php the same? My assumption is that browse.php is missing a <?php tag or something similar. if index.php and browse.php are not the same, does 'php browse.php' output php code? if so perhaps you could pastebin the code or something?

Comment: @lVlint67 `index.php` and `browse.php` are not the same, and `browse.php` isn't missing `<?php` also running `php browse.php` does not output php code (it executes it). This is `Glype` (proxy script).

Comment: does the php-fpm log contain records about browse.php being processed ?

Comment: @drookie I'm not seeing any relevant entries inside of my `php-fpm.log` file

Comment: What happens if you make index.php and browse.php the same, for testing purposes?

Comment: @RogerSherman I assume it "works", but `/browse.php` was never meant to be executed directly without `/index.php`, but at least it's not spitting out raw PHP code.

Comment: is the '_location-php.include' file in the '_includes' directory? or the same directory as X.conf? Have you tried using '/home/X/X/$request_filename' for the script name?.. we use 'fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;' here...

Comment: @lVlint67 `location-php.include` is in `_include` directory (if it'd be in wrong directory `/index.php` wouldn't work either, but it does) I tried using `$request_filename` and/or `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name`

Comment: @alexus this means that for some reason the pgp-fpm doesn't get requests to parse this browse.php, so nginx fully serves it, and it serves it like an application/octet-stream. you should dig deeper into the nginx configuration.

Comment: @drookie i agree with you 100%, `nginx` configuration inside of my question, so if you have solution / answer I'm all ears.

Comment: well, configuration is there, but not fully. what will happen if you put a `justsomerandomname.php` inside a docroot with something like `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` inside it ? will it be parsed as PHP or will nginx give it as a file ? I'm also curious about what does contains this mysterious 4XX include.

Comment: one more question - is something here ran inside a chroot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... that behaviour start to happening after implementing this:

[return error 410 for location regex? in nginx - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/646154/return-error-410-for-location-regex-in-nginx)

after retweaking it, it's now working as expected:

```
# cat X.conf 
server {
        listen      X.X.X.X:80;
    server_name X;
    root        /home/X/X/;
    index       index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include     _includes/_fastcgi.include;
    }
    location = /browse.php {
        if ($query_string ~* ^u=http) {
            return 410;
        }
        include     _includes/_fastcgi.include;
    }
}
#
```